# Error 500 during deployment of Play2 application on CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I've just created a new application on CloudBees based on the Play2 template, using *ClickStart* feature (I think it's version 2.1). The first build - automatically started - was successful. Then, I did a simple commit (just changed some HTML code in one `.scala.html` file), but the build failed, during the deployment.

Here are the logs:

```
[info] Done packaging.

Your application is ready in /scratch/jenkins/workspace/foo-bar/dist/helloworld-1.0.zip

[success] Total time: 20 s, completed Mar 20, 2013 7:51:12 AM
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins) to the *** account
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying foo-bar
[cloudbees-deployer]   Resolved from workspace as /scratch/jenkins/workspace/foo-bar/dist/helloworld-1.0.zip
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying via API server at https://api.cloudbees.com/api
[cloudbees-deployer] 0 MB
[cloudbees-deployer] 1 MB
...
[cloudbees-deployer] 21 MB
[cloudbees-deployer] 22 MB
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/foo-bar/dist/helloworld-1.0.zip at hudson.remoting.Channel@5446315a:s-b5547802
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:96)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:728)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:703)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:650)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1530)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/foo-bar/dist/helloworld-1.0.zip at hudson.remoting.Channel@5446315a:s-b5547802
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:156)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.util.IOException2: 500 - <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.3.13</center>
</body>
</html>

    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.invoke(RunEngineImpl.java:328)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.invoke(RunEngineImpl.java:264)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine$FingerprintingWrapper.invoke(Engine.java:248)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine$FingerprintingWrapper.invoke(Engine.java:236)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2236)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: 500 - <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.3.13</center>
</body>
</html>

    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientBase.processError(BeesClientBase.java:270)
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientBase.executeUpload(BeesClientBase.java:327)
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.applicationDeployArchive(BeesClient.java:576)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.invoke(RunEngineImpl.java:320)
    ... 13 more
Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm not sure about what I can do to solve this issue? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a temporarou putage for deployment endpoint. Just retry deployment (use "deploy now") and it should be ok

Comment: Hello Nicolas. Indeed, this was the problem. A new build solved the issue. Now I'm ready for Devoxx :) http://devoxx-cloudbees.linsolas.cloudbees.net/